# Routing Error - No route matches

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here's the problem, when visiting requests/index.html.erb:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"requests"}

index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", cancel_request_path %>
```

routes.rb:

```
 resources :requests do
   get 'cancel', on: :member
 end
```

requests_controller.rb:

```
 def cancel
   request = Request.find(params[:id])
   request.update_attributes(stage: "Cancelled")
   redirect_to root_path
 end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I just needed to change to this in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", cancel_request_path(request.id) %>
```

I thought all the attributes of the object would get passed to the action in params, but I guess I have to specify which params to pass to the action.

Answer (score 0):

`get 'cancel', :on => :member`

On member means, you path would be like :

```
cancel_requests_path(:id=>request_id)
```

or simply the requests object in the parameter...